# Visual Studio 2010 "default-ing" custom build

Tags: visual-studio, custom-build

as it might be clear while looking at this posts title, I'm not quite sure what to google for.
Hence I hope someone here can help me out.

Recently I happened to begin using Qt.
I don't want to use Qt creator, rather stick with Visual Studio.

The problem is when I use the Meta Object Compiler within Visual Studio.
So far I was just adding a custom build step for those header files which need to be moc-ed.

But it is very annoying to add the command-line/etc each time I add a header file which needs to be moc-ed.
So I was wondering if its possible to add an option ( like "MOC-Build" ) into the dropdown box where I usually selected "Custom Build" which does the job.

I found ( tho not tested yet ) this msdn page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/10/06/477064.aspx which explains how to add an option to the drop down box, but how can I provide a command-line/etc ?

Thanks in advance